# Is this a valid proof of the well-ordering principle?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, well-orders

Let $S \subset \mathbb{N}$

The well-ordering principle says: $\exists \ n \in S : n \leq k \ \forall k \in S$, right?

Let's assume that the negation of this proposition right above is true, that is:

$$\exists k \in S : n > k \ \forall n \in S$$

See that $n > k$ is false when $n = k$, so the initial proposition must be true.

Comment: If we have $\exists a:P(a)$ then the negation of this propositional function is $\forall a:\neg P(a)$.

Comment: Your quantifiers are off.  The negation you seek requires you to prove that "for all $n\in S$ there exists $k\in S$ with $k<n$".

Comment: Moreover, the well-ordering principle is an axiom/definition.

Comment: @manooooh I have changed completely the theme for MSE, check it. However is not complete.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! For all n in S means that n could be k, right? So k < n cannot always be true.

Comment: @Masacroso Are you following me? `;D`. I'll do it, give me a few minutes. We can put together a chat room here to discuss and lubricate your work (in the other forum it is not good to talk about it).

Comment: "There exist a $k$ for all $n$" is different than "For all $n$ there exists a $k$"  The latter is the correct negation.  Your argument is equivalent to "there is a person who is everyone's child"; the negation is "there is someone who is not the child of everyone".  But than "that person is not the child of his/her own parents".  And that is impossible.

Comment: Review your quantifiers!

Comment: Got it! Thank you @fleablood

Comment: Although your statement of the W.O. Principle is correct and is written in a way that is fine when read out loud, in order to avoid mistakes when negating a statement with quantifiers, it is safer to write it in such  a way that first (L-to-R) appearance of a quantified variable (such as $k$) is accompanied by its quantifier, E.g. $\neg (\exists n\in S\forall k\in S\;(n\leq k))\iff$ $ (\forall n\in S \;\neg (\forall k\in S\;(n\leq k)))\iff$ $\iff \forall n\in S\;(\exists k\in S\;(\neg (n\leq k)))\iff$ $\forall n\in S\;(\exists k\in S\;(n>k)).$...  (continued)

Comment: (continued). Notice how the far-left $\neg$  "percolates" through to the right, reversing $\exists$ and $\forall$ as it goes. Since it's fairly automatic it's easy to do correctly..... BTW another way to catch a logical error is to ask whether the argument would seem to apply to some other structure.  E.g. you know that $\Bbb Q$ does not satisfy the W. O. Principle but there is nothing in your proof that  says that  that $S$ could not  be equal to $\Bbb  Q^+ .$

Comment: $\exists \ n \in S : n \leq k \ \forall k \in S$ is not well formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your negation of the Well-ordering principle is not correct.

The well-ordering principle is that every non-empty set of natural numbers has a minimum element.

The negation is that,  there exists a non-empty set of natural numbers which does not have a minimum element.

If S is such a set, then it has to have an element say $a_1$, which is not minimum.

Thus it has an element $a_2< a_1$ and an element $a_3< a_2$, and so on and so forth. Is it possible to have an infinite sequence of strictly decreasing natural numbers?

Comment: That doesn't show why the OP's proof is wrong. (Which would apply to the real numbers as well as the natural numbers.)

Comment: @fleablood  I have added a statement to that extent.

Answer (score 1):

The negation is $\nexists \ n \in S : \forall k \in S : n \leq k $

which is equivalent to $\forall \ n \in S : \exists k \in S : n \not \leq k$

or in words, for each element of $S$ there is a different element of $S$ which is smaller (more precisely, not greater)

Your attempt at the negation is more like $\exists k \in S : \forall \ n \in S : n \not \leq k$ but this is not equivalent.  The key point is that you choose $k$ after choosing $n$

As an example, consider strictly positive real numbers with the usual order.  You can always find a smaller number $k$ than any particular element $n$, but the smaller number must be chosen second

Comment: Yes, I just realized my mistake. Thank you!